# Always rounding decimals up to specified precision

Tags: php, rounding, decimal

I'm looking for an elegant way to rounding up decimal numbers always up. Seems like `round(0.0045001, 5, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);` is not returning what I expected so I came up with following function;

```
function roundUp($number, $precision) {
    $rounded = round($number, $precision);

    if ($rounded < $number) {
        $add = '0';
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $precision; $i++) {
            if ($i == 1) $add = '.';
            $add .= ($i == $precision) ? '1' : '0';
        }
        $add = (float) $add;
        $rounded = $rounded + $add;
    }

    return $rounded;
}
```

I was wondering if there is any other, more elegant way to achieve this?

**Expected Result :**
`var_dump(roundUp(0.0045001, 5)) // 0.00451;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function roundup_prec($in,$prec)
{
    $fact = pow(10,$prec);
    return ceil($fact*$in)/$fact;
}

echo roundup_prec(0.00450001,4)."\n";
echo roundup_prec(0.00450001,5);
```

gives:

```
0.0046
0.00451
```

Comment: I don't know why I used it with `pow()` but couldn't get the correct result. I guess I did some mistake which I didn't notice. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
function roundUp($number, $precision) {
    $rounded = round($number, $precision);

    if ($rounded < $number) {
        $add = '0';
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $precision; $i++) {
            if ($i == 1) $add = '.';
            $add .= ($i == $precision) ? '1' : '0';
        }
        $add = (float) $add;
        $rounded = $rounded + $add;
    }

    return ceil($rounded);
}
```

Comment: if I wanted to use ceil, I wouldn't go through all these trouble and just use `ceil(0.0045001)` right? Thanks for the effort though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ceil(x)` you can also use `(int)x`, which gives the same result

EDIT: OK forget about that, I meant `(int)x + 1` and thats not true for a number that's already rounded.